# Any better way to read Json array

Tags: c#, json

I have a json file - `WorkflowNames.json` with contents as -

```
["ImportOrder", "ValidateOrder", "ProcessOrder", "ArchiveOrder"]
```

My C# code to read this json file is -

```
private Dictionary<string, bool> GetWorkflowNames()
{
  var appDataFolder = ConfigurationMgr.GetAppPath("App_Data");
  var jsonFilePath = Path.Combine(appDataFolder, "WorkflowNames.json");
  JArray workflowNames = (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(jsonFilePath));

  var workflowNamesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
  foreach (JToken workflowName in workflowNames)
  {
    workflowNamesDictionary.Add(workflowName.ToString(), false);
  }

  return workflowNamesDictionary;
}
```

My code runs fine. But because this is my first attempt to read data from a json file, I am not sure about these -

1. As a json standard, any data in json file should be represented as key value pair. If I have just an array to read from json file, is it okay to declare as above?
2. Is there any better way, can I improve/simplify above C# code?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Json.Net has support for collections built-in. You should be able to use the generic version of `DeserializeObject` like this:

```
private Dictionary<string, bool> GetWorkflowNames()
{
    var appDataFolder = ConfigurationMgr.GetAppPath("App_Data");
    var jsonFilePath = Path.Combine(appDataFolder, "WorkflowNames.json");
    var jsonString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(jsonFilePath);
    var workflowNames = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(jsonString);
    return workflowNames.ToDictionary(name => name, _ => false);
}
```

There are still a few things I would clean up in your code:

Add a using for `System.IO` and use `File` without the namespace. You could also use a static using like this `using static System.IO.File;` and access `ReadAllText` directly but I generally dislike this unless the class is very focussed and heavily using `File`.

You'll notice that I introduced a local variable `jsonString` as I don't like hiding the file access in the call to deserialize the json. I try to stick rigidly to one thing happening per line. Simple and clear code is best when you want to maintain it 2 years later.

I'd also recommend using `.ToDictionary` as it shortens the code and makes it very obvious what you're doing. Having said that, I would have this return an `IEnumerable<string>` instead of a dictionary. It's not clear why this returns a dictionary and `GetWorkflowNames` sounds like it would be perfectly reasonable to return the list.

Comment: Thanks RobH, really appreciate your detailed review. I loved your statement "I try to stick rigidly to one thing happening per line." 
The reason for returning Dictionary object is to add to another dictionary (existing legacy code) in the calling method.